# RuntimeError: Could not infer dtype of Image

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I was trying to write a code for object detection. I used a dataset of my own and all things seemed ok. But in training, I get the mentioned error. I defined a collate_fn as:

```
def collate_fn(batch):
    return tuple(zip(*batch))
```

Then data_loader as:

```
data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader( dataset, batch_size=2, shuffle=True, 
                                         collate_fn=collate_fn)
```

Finally, in training stage, I get this error:

```
num_epochs = 5
losses = []

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
   for i, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(data_loader):
       inputs = torch.tensor(inputs).to(device)
       targets = torch.tensor(targets).to(device)
```

the error is:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-f5d22c9fc6ce> in <module>
      4 for epoch in range(num_epochs):
      5     for i, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(data_loader):
----> 6         inputs = torch.tensor(inputs).to(device)
      7         targets = torch.tensor(targets).to(device)
      8 

RuntimeError: Could not infer dtype of Image
```

At first, I had the error:

```
'tuple' object has no attribute 'to'
```

when my code was in the way:

```
inputs= inputs.to(device)
```

But changing code to:

```
inputs = torch.tensor(inputs).to(device)
```

Maybe solved that error. But Now, I am getting the mentioned error

```
RuntimeError: Could not infer dtype of Image
```

What is wrong here?
What should I do?